# Replacing '(' with '-' in C++

Tags: c++

I've tried:

```
versionString = versionString.replace(versionString.begin(), versionString.end(), '(' , '-' );
```

The result is: "--------------". Basically replacing all the characters. What is that?

versionString is a basic string.

Comment: Might have something to do with the fact that `std::string` [has no overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) of `replace` that accepts two characters. Unless of course you aren't using `std::string`, in which case you need to provide one hella better [mcve].

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/

Comment: This one has tripped me up more than once, as it doesn't do the same thing as [`std::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) at all. (One thing I've learned is to always be cautious around `std::string` and assume that my assumptions are probably wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at e.g. [this `std::string::replace` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) you will see that there's no overload that takes the arguments you pass. Something the compiler really should warn you about.

The closes one is number 6:

```
basic_string& replace( const_iterator first, const_iterator last,
                       size_type count2, CharT ch );
```

which replaces the range with `count2` copies of `ch`.

That is, you replace your string with `'('` number of dashes. With [ASCII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) that `'('` will be converted to the integer `40` (it's this conversion the compiler should have warned you about).

One solution is to repeatedly [`find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) the character you want to replace, and replace only that single character.

A much simpler solution is to use the [standard algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) function [`std::replace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace):

```
std::replace(begin(versionString), end(versionString), '(', '-');
```